# Is there a way to update PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql

Is there a simple way to add something to PreparedStatement?
For example:

```
ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT nazivpredmeta, iddokumenta, nazivdokumenta, putanja, datumskeniranja FROM skeniranidokumenti , predmet WHERE " 
if(osnovnibroj!=null){
    ps.add("predmet.osnovnibroj=? ");
    ps.setObject(1, osnovnibroj);
}
if(iddepartmana!=null){
 if(osnovnibroj!=null){
    ps.add("AND skeniranidokumenti=? ");
    ps.setObject(1, iddepartmana);
}else{
     ps.add("skeniranidokumenti=? ");
    ps.setObject(1, iddepartmana);
}
```

I know that there is not add method, my question is: is there something i can use?

Comment: no. once it's prepared, the statement is done. it'd be the equivalent of making a loaf of bread, then realizing you wanted to add raisins. the raisins have to be added to the dough before baking. adding afterwards is just not practical. e.g. it's build -> prepare, not build->prepare->build->buildbuildbuildbuild->execute.

Answer (score 0):

You could construct your **`SELECT`** statement using a `StringBuilder`, and then pass the completed string to `connection.prepareStatement()`.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("SELECT DISTINCT nazivpredmeta, iddokumenta, nazivdokumenta, putanja, datumskeniranja FROM skeniranidokumenti , predmet WHERE TRUE");
if (osnovnibroj != null)
{
    sb.append(" AND predmet.osnovnibroj = ?");
}
if (iddepartmana != null)
{
    sb.append(" AND skeniranidokumenti = ?");
}

ps = connection.prepareStatement(sb.toString());

if (iddepartmana != null)
{
    if (osnovnibroj != null)
    {
        ps.setObject(1, osnovnibroj);
        ps.setObject(2, iddepartmana);
    }
    else
    {
        ps.setObject(1, iddepartmana);
    }
}
else if (osnovnibroj != null)
{
    ps.setObject(1, osnovnibroj);
}
```

Note that I've used the `WHERE TRUE` trick to simplify the logic of constructing the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't.. Simply you can do like this:

```
 String query="SELECT DISTINCT nazivpredmeta, iddokumenta, nazivdokumenta, putanja, datumskeniranja FROM skeniranidokumenti , predmet WHERE ";

          if(osnovnibroj!=null){
              query=query+"predmet.osnovnibroj=? ";
              ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
              ps.setObject(1, osnovnibroj);
          }
```